# Is there a way to avoid the additional cast List<T> into MyOwnCollection : List<T> in C#?

Tags: c#

Is there any way for me to avoid the additional cast when I cast a `List<T>` to my own collection, which is nothing but a derivate of `List<T>`?

---

#### Example:

```
ScreenCollection screens = screenRepository.GetAll().ToList();
// fails because ScreenCollection != return of ToList() which is List<Screen>

// However, 
public class ScreenCollection : List<Screen>
```

I know I could do the following, simple enough:

```
ScreenCollection screens = (ScreenCollection)screenRepository.GetAll().ToList();
```

I would like to avoid that additional casting, if possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't possible and in fact, your cast is wrong too. Just because `ScreenCollection` derives from `List<Screen>` doesn't mean every `List<Screen>` instance also implements `ScreenCollection`.

.NET 4.0 and C#4 will provide contravariance and covariance on interface types, which would go some way to mitigating the situation you face, but it doesn't provide variance for lists.

One way to address your issue would be to have an extension method or constructor for `ScreenCollection` (depending on whether you own the code or not) that could create a new instance based on a given `IEnumerable<Screen>` or `IList<Screen>`. You could also consider refactoring your `ScreenCollection` type (if it is yours to refactor) so that it encapsulates a `List<Screen>` rather than inherits from it, and then just wrap the new `List<Screen>` instance from `ToList()`.

Comment: I like your explanation; +1; IMO the best answer.

Answer (score 7):

Subclassing `List<T>` is rarely useful - except to give it a name; `Collection<T>` at least gives you the option to override some things...

In your example, I'm assuming that `.ToList()` is the LINQ extension method - in which case, it really is returning a `List<T>`, not a `ScreenColleciton`. <s>You could add an implicit conversion operator, but I don't think that is a good idea</s> (turns out that not only is it not a good idea: it isn't possible ;-p credit: Aistina - comments).

If it *isn't* the LINQ extension method - then simply type it to return the right thing...

Comment: You can't add an implicit conversion operator, because "user-defined conversions to or from a base class are not allowed". Just tried that.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the cast won't even work. You can cast a ScreenCollection to a List`<`Screen`>` but you can't do it the other way around. Consider - what if you added an extra property to your ScreenCollection class that is not present on an ordinary List. What would the value of this property be if you could cast any List`<`Screen`>` to a ScreenCollection?

Instead, you can use the List`<`T`>` constructor that takes an IEnumerable`<`T`>` as a parameter:

```
var screens = new ScreenCollection(screenRepository.GetAll());
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible in .NET 3.0... In 4.0, you won't need  to cast.

Comment: C# 4 doesn't provide variance of lists: http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/02/what-c-40-covariance-doesn-do.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to do this -

The cast will fail, as well, since (at runtime), `List<Screen>` is not a `ScreenCollection`.

If you made your class implement `IList<Screen>` instead of deriving `List<Screen>`, and encapulated the list as a member variable, you could potentially make a constructor that took the existing list and just "wrapped" it in your class.  This would allow you to write:

```
ScreenCollection screens = new ScreenCollection(screenRepository.GetAll().ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a generic method override on your repository. Something like:

> var screens = screenRepository.GetAll< ScreenCollection >();